Solve the recurrence $T(n) = nT(n/2) +n - 1$
I have to solve the recurrence $T(n) = nT\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right) +n - 1$ and also find the bounds.
I tried solving it using substitution and I get $T(n) = \dfrac{n^k}{2^{k(k-1)/2}}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^k}\right) -1$ but I don't know how to get bounds from here even if I assume $n= 2^k$. I then tried dividing both sides by $n$ in the original recurrence equation and that leads to $O(n\log n)$. My two approaches to solve the recurrence.

Fwiw, I think it would make the question more complete (and attractive) if you edit your approaches into the question itself, instead of an image.

Making $n = 2^m$ we have
$$
T\left(2^m\right)=2^m T\left(2^{m-1}\right)+2^m-1
$$
This recurrence can be recast as
$$
R(m) = 2^m R(m-1) + 2^m - 1
$$
now if $R_h$ and $R_p$ are the homogeneous and particular solutions for this linear recurrence, we have
$$
\cases{
R_h(m) = 2^m R_h(m-1)\\
R_p(m) = 2^m R_p(m-1) + 2^m - 1\\
R(m) = R_h(m)+R_p(m)
}
$$
The homogeneous solution is straightforward
$$
R_h(m) = c_0\prod_{k=0}^m2^k
$$
For the particular, we assume $R_p(m) = c_m\prod_{k=0}^m2^k$ and after substitution
$$
c_m\prod_{k=0}^m2^k = 2^mc_{m-1}\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}2^k+2^m-1
$$
so
$$
c_m - c_{m-1} = \frac{2^m-1}{\prod_{k=0}^m2^k}
$$
and
$$
c_m = \sum_{j=0}^m\frac{2^j-1}{\prod_{k=0}^j2^k}
$$
and finally
$$
R(m) = \left(c_0 + \sum_{j=0}^m\frac{2^j-1}{\prod_{k=0}^j2^m}\right)\prod_{k=0}^m2^k
$$
Going backwards we recover $T(n)$. Remember that $m = \log_2 n$ hence from
$$
R(m) = c_1 2^{\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}-1
$$
we have
$$
T(n) = c_1 n^{\frac 12(1+\log_2 n)}-1
$$
NOTE
$$
{\prod_{k=0}^m2^k} = 2^{\frac{(m+1)m}{2}}
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{2^j-1}{2^{j(j+1)/2}} = 1-2^{-\frac{ (m+1)m}{2} }
$$
